# Get info from a card using RFID c#

Tags: c#, rfid

**I am trying to get information reading a card using the RFID Gigatek UR110/115U.**

This card just has a code, and I want to read it and store it in a variable.
My reader is in *COM4* and is connected by *USB*.

I am trying something like this:

**Designer**:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
   {
   //...
   this.serialPort1 = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(this.components);
   //...
   this.serialPort1.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.serialPort1_DataReceived);
   //...
   private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPort1;
   //...
}
```

**Method**:

```
    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
        {
            String aux = this.serialPort1.ReadLine();

            if (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aux)[0] == 2)
                aux = aux.Substring(1);


            if (aux.Length > 10)
                aux = aux.Substring(0, 10);

            this.Lectura = aux;

            if (this.serialPort1.IsOpen)
                this.serialPort1.Close();

            this.tiempo_esperado = 0;
        }
    }
```

But this is not working. What could am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your reader will have come with a manual, SDK and/or developer's guide that will document their serial communications protocol and _should_ come with examples.

Comment: I note that "RFID" is not a specific technical term because there are many different incompatible specifications and standards for RFID. Can you be more specific? (e.g. EPC Class 1 Gen 2 UHF, various VHF standards - and different specs entirely for NFC. Have you verified that the card you want to read is using the same RFID standard as your reader?

Comment: Is `aux` `string.Empty`? If you're using `ReadLine`, you have to make sure received data including new line string. Use `Read` or `ReadExisting` to check actual data. Then set `SerialPort.NewLine` to correct string if you want to use ReadLine.